# После обновления страницы не исчезает кнопка

Tags: php

Код.

```
if ( $ids > '0' ) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" name="smb">
          </form>';
}
if( isset( $_POST[ 'smb' ] ) ) {
        тут выполняется скрипт который удаляет из базы строку с $ids
}
```

Страница обновляется, но чтобы кнопка исчезла - нужно второй раз обновлять страницу.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
if( !isset( $_POST[ 'smb' ] ) ) {
    if ( $ids > '0' ) {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="smb">
        </form>';
    }
} else {
    тут выполняется скрипт который удаляет из базы строку с $ids
}
```